# Cannot get minidump file of win 7 after it is get the bluescreen error

Tags: windows-7, minidumps

My PC run Win 7 pro OS. And it get bluescreen error, and I want to collect all minidump files in C driver.

But there are no minidump files. I try to config my PC as these steps of each solutions below, but the issue was happended again:

**Solution 1:**

Go to the Control Panel, choose 'System And Security', and then click 'System', and then click the 'Advanced System Settings' link.

In the opened window, click the 'Advanced' tab and then inside the 'Startup And Recovery' frame, click the 'Settings' button.

In the opened 'Startup And Recovery' window,  there is 'Write Debugging Information' section. You should set the combo-box in this section to 'Small memory dump', and then click 'ok' to confirm the change.

**Solutions 2:**

I also make this MiniDump change in the Registry, by setting the following value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl]
"CrashDumpEnabled"=dword:00000003
```

Then I restart my PC to affect the configuration.

BUT, I still dont see any minidump files on C driver.

What should I do next ?

Thank.

Comment: What's the hard disk model? Minidump files are usually stored in `C:\Windows\Minidump`. If you don't get any, that could mean the file system and/or the disk aren't healthy. Open a command prompt as administrator and run this command: `chkdsk /r`. You'll be asked to perform a full disk check at next boot. Restart Windows, and report back any errors that may be detected. Check the [event logs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) too. Also, disable the automatic restart option, and post here the blue screen technical details.

Comment: The default is supposed to be in a folder called %systemroot%\Minidump\ (normally C:\Windows\Minidump\).  The folder only gets created when a BSOD occurs. This folder may be a system folder so ensure that your explorer settings are set to allow you to view system and hidden folders.

Comment: have you disabled the pagefile? Windows needs the pagefile to write dumps.

Comment: have you looked if you've disabled the pagefile?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thank you! That has worked for me. I think you should post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need adequate disk space and adequate pagefile on your system boot drive for crash dumps to be properly created. See this link: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/01/08/understanding-crash-dump-files.aspx